# Plot lme4 reordered Penicillin data with lattice

Tags: r, plot, lattice, lme4, mixed-models

I am reading the lme4 documentation book to learn how to analyze linear mixed-effects models. I am trying to reproduce all steps, but I have an issue when trying to plot the reordered Penicillin dataset as it appears in the section 8.2.2 Multiple Random Effects of this website (http://www.john-ros.com/Rcourse/lme.html) Figure link: http://www.john-ros.com/Rcourse/Rcourse_files/figure-html/unnamed-chunk-181-1.png

So far, I have been able to reorder the data frame and plot the dots successfully with different shapes, but I am unable to link the dots for each sample in the right reordered way. They plot in the original order and the plot looks really messy.

I have tried to look for the code for this plot online but I'm not able to locate it anywhere. I'm sorry in advance if this is a trivial question.

Here you have the code I have written so far:

```
library(lme4)
require(lattice)

myPCH <- 1:6
myLTY <- 1:6


# Plotting only the dots in the right way
xyplot(reorder(plate, diameter) ~ diameter, Penicillin,
       xlab="Diameter of growth inhibition zone (mm)",
       ylab = "Plate",
       groups=factor(sample,labels=as.character(unique(Penicillin$sample))),
       pch=myPCH, col=1:6,
       key =  list(columns=6,
                   text = list(as.character(unique(Penicillin$sample))),
                   points = list(pch=myPCH, col=1:6)),
       type = c("g","p"))


# Adding the lines in the wrong order (Modified so that they have 
# different styles
xyplot(reorder(plate, diameter) ~ diameter, data=Penicillin,
       xlab="Diameter of growth inhibition zone (mm)",
       ylab = "Plate",
       groups=factor(sample,labels=as.character(unique(Penicillin$sample))),
       pch=myPCH, col=1:6,
       lty=myLTY,
       key =  list(columns=6,
                   text = list(as.character(unique(Penicillin$sample))),
                   points = list(pch=myPCH, col=1:6)),
       type = c("g","p","l"))


# Trying to plot the dots and the lines separately with the 
# "panel = function(x, y, groups,...)" lattice function 

xyplot(reorder(plate, diameter) ~ diameter, data=Penicillin,
       groups=factor(sample,labels=as.character(unique(Penicillin$sample))),
       xlab="Diameter of growth inhibition zone (mm)",
       ylab = "Plate",
       key =  list(columns=6,
                   text = list(as.character(unique(Penicillin$sample))),
                   points = list(pch=myPCH, col=1:6)),
       panel = function(x, y, groups,...) {

       panel.xyplot(x, y,
                      pch=myPCH, col=1:6,
                      type = c("g","p"));

       panel.linejoin(x, y,
                        lty=myLTY, col=1:6,
                        type = c("g","l"))
       })


sessionInfo()
```

I would like to plot, the points and the lines with different shapes as it is plotted in the original png picture I mentioned before.

This is my sessionInfo():

```
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] MEMSS_0.9-2     lattice_0.20-38 ggplot2_3.1.0   lme4_1.1-19     Matrix_1.2-15  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.0       rstudioapi_0.9.0 magrittr_1.5     bindr_0.1.1      splines_3.5.1   
 [6] MASS_7.3-51.1    tidyselect_0.2.5 munsell_0.5.0    colorspace_1.4-0 R6_2.3.0        
[11] rlang_0.3.1      minqa_1.2.4      plyr_1.8.4       dplyr_0.7.8      tools_3.5.1     
[16] grid_3.5.1       gtable_0.2.0     nlme_3.1-137     withr_2.1.2      lazyeval_0.2.1  
[21] assertthat_0.2.0 tibble_2.0.1     crayon_1.3.4     bindrcpp_0.2.2   purrr_0.2.5     
[26] nloptr_1.2.1     glue_1.3.0       labeling_0.3     compiler_3.5.1   pillar_1.3.1    
[31] scales_1.0.0     pkgconfig_2.0.2
```

Thank you very much for your help,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order in which the lines are connected are actually dependent on the order that the observations appear in the data. To get the figure most easily, you just need to sort the data. Here I make a copy and do the sorting

```
p2 <- transform(Penicillin, pd = reorder(plate, diameter))
p2 <- p2[order(p2$pd),]
```

Then I can use that for the plotting with the first code chunk you created

```
xyplot(pd ~ diameter, data=p2, ...)
```

which gives the following plot

[image: different colors and points]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I hadn't thought about reordering the original data frame in the same way it was being transformed in the model definition.